# How do I bookmark root in files?

Tags: gnome, files

In Ubuntu 22.10 I use the default file manager, Files.

[image]

I want to add root "/" as first (preferably) location in left menu.

[image]

The menu add bookmark is disabled

[image]

So why is "Files" hiding root?

Comment: It is not hiding it , it simply is not a place you can bookmark. Why do you want access to root like this?

Comment: Just make a link to / with ln command then mark it

Comment: @david I need / because i'm developer

Answer (score 0):

@petep solution is way to. I created link to root and renamed it later so it looks genuine

```
ln -s / /home/user/rootln
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the config for bookmarks manually. It lives in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`

So to add root, you could just run:

```
echo "file:///" >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```